# SPGridView Filter menu shown separated of LinkButton with templated header

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I use Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView control to write out data.
Filtering is allowed for grid.
Columns contain templated column, it define ItemTemplate and HeaderTemplate:

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="linkTitleHeader" runat="server" Text="TitleHeader1"
               CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Title"></asp:LinkButton>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>                   
             <a href="some javascript">some text</a>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

It works fine, shows header as link, its performs sorting by click, but filter menu 
show on separate row:

[image: a]

i expect that it shows as:

[image: a]

I already try with no result:

1. Leave Text property empty and define other properties
2. Set Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls.Menu Text programmaticaly after
   databind
3. Set link text by javascript

Have any ideas how to join Menu with LinkButton ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must also specify the properties of SPGridView : FilterDataFields, FilteredDataSourcePropertyName, FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat. Maybe this article will help you [link](http://vspug.com/bobsbonanza/2007/07/02/filtering-with-spgridview/)

Comment: These properties are already set in Page_Load, and this not solved problem:               Grid.FilterDataFields = ",Title";
Grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
Grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} = '{0}'";

Comment: Try to set these properties on the aspx page. And yet, if you have only one field "Title", then the value of FilterDataFields should look like "Title" without a comma

Comment: no effect =(, set it from pageload or in aspx - no matter. "Title" show here for example, it have more columns, with comma or not - header looks same